# how to show Double type data in data grid view from database c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, double

i am trying to load double type data from sqlite database in to Data grid view it throws an [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hykGW.png)  if i change DB columns type to Integer it works perfect, Please give any solution?

Comment: Can you please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i have sqlite database which contains Columns of data type{DOUBLE}, I want to upload DB data in Datagridview but it gives an exception [I have attached an image of exception above].

Comment: What I meant with [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is: "Show us your code". Without a good scope of your code it's impossible for us to give you a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please, update your question.

Comment: Obviously, the `DataError` indicates exactly what you describe… trying to put an `int` into a `double` type. If it works with `int`, then it would appear the data itself is an `int` and not a `double`. What part of this is mysterious?